# Rails Header : how to set form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, header

In my header, users can add an "item" via a form. I want this option to be available on each page, so I have in my header :

```
<%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>

           <div>
              <div class="title"><%= f.label :name, "Name" %></div>
              <div class="champ"><%= f.text_field :name %></div>
          </div>

          <div>
              <%= f.submit "add this item" %>
          </div>
<% end %>
```

But it forces me to add this in each controller :

```
def action
    @item = Item.new
end
```

How can I avoid it ? Using Application controller ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a method in application controller and use `before_filter`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ..
  before_filter :initialize_item

  def initialize_item
    @item = Item.new
  end
end
```

initialize_item method will be executed on each request now.

Comment: @Maxxx If this works for you, then don't you want to accept as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<%= form_for(Item.new) ...
```

But if the item is invalid, the form will be empty (since you create a new item for the form, not using the one prefilled with values and validated by your controller). You may try:

```
<%= form_for(@item || Item.new)...
```